# Creating a deck of cards in java with a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to create a deck and apply a suite to each one, for example:

`cardValue[0][1]` and convert it into `cardValue[Spade][1]`

but I don't understand how to convert it. What I have currently:

```
        int cardValues[][];
        for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b <= 12; b++)
            {
                cardValues[][] += cardValues[a][b];
                if(cardValues[a][b] == cardValues[a][0])
                {
                    cardValues[a][b] = 5;
                }
                else if(cardValues[a][b] > cardValues[a][0] || cardValues[a][b] < cardValues[a][10])
                {   
                    cardValues[a][b] = 1;
                }
                else if(cardValues[a][b] == cardValues[a][10])
                {
                    cardValues[a][b] = 2;
                }
                else if(cardValues[a][b] == cardValues[a][11])
                {
                    cardValues[a][b] = 3;
                }
                else if(cardValues[a][b] == cardValues[a][12])
                {
                    cardValues[a][b] = 4;
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't understand how to convert the 0, 1, 2, and 3 into spades, diamonds, clubs, hearts.

Comment: I would create an Enumerable class to manage the suits...

Comment: would it be better if I converted it into a String instead of a int and if it equals a certain value, to equal that string for example: cardValues["Spade"]["10"]

Comment: Hum I think that in this case a String is not the best idea... You can still keep your numbers and do whatever you need with q switch case in the end. Or you can go with the enum, here you have a good reference for what you need and why you should use them  https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/enums/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like that:

**Suit.java**

```
public enum Suit {
    SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, HEARTS
}
```

**Card.java**

```
public class Card {

    private Suit suit;
    private String value;

    public Card(Suit suit, String value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
    public void setSuit(Suit suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] values = new String[]{"K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "A"};

        Card[] deck = new Card[52];

        int i = 0;
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (String value : values) {
                deck[i++] = new Card(suit, value);
            }
        }

        for (Card card : deck) {
            System.out.println(card.getValue() + " of " + card.getSuit());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how this works, one last thing, if I wanted to have it print the whole deck with this, how would I set that up with it?

Comment: for (Card card : deck) {
System.out.println(card.getValue() + " of " + card.getSuit());
}